# JavaCV Create Mat from Resource (InputStream)

Tags: java, image-processing, javacv, matchtemplate

I use JavaCV (not OpenCV). My goal is to obtain a `Mat` object from an image that is stored as a Resource. Then I'm going to pass this `Mat` into `opencv_imgproc.matchTemplate` method. I've managed to write this **bad** code:

```
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Lenna32.png");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
    Frame f = new Java2DFrameConverter().getFrame(image);
    Mat mat = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat().convert(f);
```

This works in *some* cases. The problems are:

1. For png images that has transparency channel (that is 32BPP), it shifts channels, so that `R=00 G=33 B=66 A=FF` turns to `R=33 G=66 B=FF`
   [image: Lenna 32BPP color shift]
2. On my target environment, I can't use `ImageIO`
3. There are too many object conversions `InputStream -> BufferedImage -> Frame -> Mat`. I feel like there should be a simple and effective way to do this.

What is the best way to create Mat from a Resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this by reading bytes from InputStream and passing them into imdecode function:

```
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("Lenna32.png");
int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[16 * 1024];
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}
byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
Mat mat = imdecode(new Mat(bytes), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

Comment: If you can use Apache Commons IO you can convert the input stream directly to a byte array with a one-liner with IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

Comment: ...or simply use built-in `inputStream.readAllBytes()` extension function in kotlin

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, in order to convert InputStream to Mat, @Kotlin:

```kotlin
val bytes = inputStream.readBytes()
val mat = Mat(1, bytes.size, CvType.CV_8UC1)
mat.put(0, 0, bytes)
return Imgcodecs.imdecode(mat, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```